# Unable to compile apache-Tomcat on AIX6.1

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, gcc

I am trying to install Apache-Tomcat on AIX6.1, and I am failing to compile (./configure command) below the log file, can someone assist me in pointing into a right direction to solve this issue?`enter code here`

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1384: checking build system type
configure:1402: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:1410: checking host system type
configure:1424: result: powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
configure:1433: checking cached host system type
configure:1444: result: ok
configure:1501: checking for gcc
configure:1517: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:1527: result: gcc
configure:1771: checking for C compiler version
configure:1774: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
Could not load program gcc:
        Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could     not be loaded.
    Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
configure:1777: $? = 255
configure:1779: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Could not load program gcc:
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not     be loaded.
    Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
configure:1782: $? = 255
configure:1784: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
Could not load program gcc:
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not     be loaded.
    Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
configure:1787: $? = 255
configure:1810: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:1813: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
Could not load program gcc:
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not be loaded.
    Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
```